# How to decompress a file or folder in java?

Tags: java, compression

We have code for compressing file in java.

Java comes with “java.util.zip” library to perform data compression in ZIP format.

The overall concept is quite straightforward.

- Read file with “FileInputStream”
- Add the file name to “ZipEntry” and output it to “ZipOutputStream“

And for importing Zip folder in a program is:

> `import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;`
>
> `import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;`

But can anyone tell me how to decompress a file?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered in below link:-

[Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html)